# TypeScript: do question marks for optional CLASS properties actually make any difference?

Tags: typescript, types, null, undefined

In TypeScript I already know that you use a question mark to mark a **function argument** or **interface property** as optional.  And TypeScript will give you errors when you neglect to set non-optional values when using the function or interface.

But TypeScript also allows you to use a question mark in **class** properties, e.g:

```
class MyClass {

    propertyWithoutQuestionMark:string;
    propertyWithQuestionMark?:string; // what's the difference?

}
```

Is there any difference between the two properties above in terms of how TypeScript will allow you to use (not or use) them or the class in general?

Everything I'm finding on the web just seems to be talking about function arguments and interfaces.  But haven't found the explanation of what it means in **CLASS** properties.

If possible some example code would be good to show something where TypeScript will report an error for one of the properties, but not the other.

Comment: The question mark means the property can be `null` (or `undefined`). Otherwise you will get an error when you don't assign it in the constructor

Comment: Thanks @UnholySheep

There doesn't seem to be a requirement to define any of the properties in the constructor though?  Unless it's related to some specific tsconfig setting?

Although I noticed that it does show an error if I specifically try to set `myPropertyWithoutQuestionMark=undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your example and compiling with enabled `strictNullChecks` and `strictPropertyInitialization` already yields an error (compiling without these two options enabled will not give an error), as can be seen [on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20propertyWithoutQuestionMark%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%20%20propertyWithQuestionMark%3F%3A%20string%3B%20%2F%2F%20what's%20the%20difference%3F%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D):

`Property 'propertyWithoutQuestionMark' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

In order for it to compile you have to initialize at least the non-nullable property in the constructor or use an initializer, e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
  propertyWithoutQuestionMark:string;
  propertyWithQuestionMark?: string;
  constructor(parameterOne: string) {
    this.propertyWithoutQuestionMark = parameterOne;
  }
}
```

The optional property `propertyWithQuestionMark` does not need to be initialized in the constructor